# exact sequence induced by restriction to closed subscheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles

I'm somewhat embarrassed to be confused about this issue after a while studying algebraic geometry, but here goes.

Let $\iota: Y \hookrightarrow X$ be the inclusion of a closed subscheme, $U$ is the complement of $Y$ in $X$, and $\mathcal{F}$ a sheaf on $X$. Then one has an exact sequence of sheaves

$$0 \rightarrow \mathcal{F}_U \rightarrow \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{F}_Y \rightarrow 0.$$

Here $\mathcal{F}_Y = \iota_* (\iota^{-1} \mathcal{F})$ and $\mathcal{F}_U = j_{!} (j^{-1}\mathcal{F})$ where $j: U \hookrightarrow X$ is the natural open embedding.

On the other hand, one has the exact sequence of the closed subscheme

$$ 0 \rightarrow \mathcal{I}_Y \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow \iota_* \mathcal{O}_Y \rightarrow 0.$$

If $\mathcal{F}$ is locally free, then we can tensor this up to get the sequence

$$ 0 \rightarrow \mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{I}_Y \rightarrow \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{F} \otimes \iota_* \mathcal{O}_Y \rightarrow 0.$$

I had always thought, and even denoted, both the sheaves $\mathcal{F}_Y$ and $\mathcal{F} \otimes \iota_* \mathcal{O}_Y$ as $\mathcal{F}|_Y$ (note that $\mathcal{F} \otimes \iota_* \mathcal{O}_Y = \iota_* (\iota^* \mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{O}_X)$, but I guess they can't be equal since e.g. $\mathcal{F}_U \neq \mathcal{F}(-Y)$ - one is a vector bundle and the other isn't. Somewhere in all the sheafification stuff, I've lost my head and I'm 
seeking some intuition about the difference between $\mathcal{F}_Y$ and $\mathcal{F} \otimes \iota_* \mathcal{O}_Y$. For instance, continuing to assume that $\mathcal{F}$ is a vector bundle, the second sheaf (I think) should correspond to the restriction of the vector bundle to $Y$; what is the first sheaf?

Comment: Maybe this is not where the confusion comes from, but just a quick comment: The ideal sheaf of $Y$ in $X$ is not $\mathcal O_X(-Y)$, in general - but only if $Y$ is a divisor in $X$.

Comment: Yes of course, that is the context I was thinking of, but I'll edit it for the more general setting.

Comment: It appears to me that the subtlety is in the difference between $\iota^{-1}\mathcal{F}$ and $\iota^*\mathcal{F}$; one doesn't have the natural structure of an $\mathcal{O}_Y$ -module and the other does.

Comment: Yes, I agree that they are different but I'm not sure how to think of this difference intuitively, or geometrically, and am hoping that there are some enlightening examples or something.

Answer (score 2):

For any sheaf, $i^{-1}\mathcal F$ doesn't change the stalks.  You just take the stalks of $\mathcal F$, but only pay attention to them at the points of $y$.
So if $x$ is a closed point in $X$ and $i: x \hookrightarrow X$ is the embedding,
$i^{-1} \mathcal O_X$ is literally the stalk at $x$, i.e. $\mathcal O_{X,x}$.

This is quite a bit different from $i^*\mathcal O_{X,x}$, which is the residue field
at $x$.

As you guessed, $i^*$ applied to locally free sheaves corresponds to restricting vector bundles.  The $i^{-1}$ operation isn't so geometrically meaningful for coherent sheaves (other than as a step on the way to defining $i^*$), but is important for more topological considerations (e.g. if we were working with locally constant or constructible sheaves on the complex topology of a complex variety, or on the etale topology of a scheme; it also comes up in the proof of Grothendieck's vanishing theorem, which is of a purely topological nature).